# Defining list of new variables at once (in a loop?)

Tags: variable-definitions, procedural-programming

I have a list of solutions Subscript[x, 1][t], i = 1,...,n (n given).

I would like to use these variables to define new variables such as:

```
i = 1;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
 Subscript[X, i][t_] := Subscript[x, i][t] /. sol]
```

I know that this code is not working and I know why. However, I would like to ask you if there is a way how to define these variables at once (without having to define them one by one)?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

David.

Comment: TIP: never use `Subscript` nor `For`. They are one of the main sources of confusion.

Comment: Here you could try `Table[X[i][t_] := x[i][t] /. sol, {i, 1, n}]`. Does this work as expected?

Comment: Thank you very much, I replaced Substrict and with some more changes itw working properly now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) to postpone the [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) operation until after the RHS has been defined. Here is an example:

```
Clear[Subscript];
sol = Subscript[x, i_][t] -> t^i;
n = 10;

Activate @ Table[
    Inactive[SetDelayed][
        Subscript[X,i][t_],
        Subscript[x,i][t]/.sol
    ],
    {i, n}
];
```

Check:

```
Subscript[X, 4][2]
```

> 16

Comment: Many thanks, that helped me a lot!